# Open set in a general metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let d define a metric on an infinite set $M$. Show that there exists an open set $U$ such that $U$ and its complement are infinite. (Infinite referring to cardinality in both instances)

I know this is trivial with the discrete metric and also trivial on the reals with the usual metric but I'm not sure how to proceed for a general metric.

Comment: You can find a proof [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.math.uic.edu%2F~hurder%2Fmath445%2Fhomeworks%2Fexercise20090921sols.pdf&ei=M6KXVbmEEISpsAXduig&usg=AFQjCNFPs4XuqfQORJksTu_sxMbKS_xZag&bvm=bv.96952980,d.b2w&cad=rja) (problem 7).

Comment: Thank you, guess I didn't Google hard enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of isolated points of $M$.

If $S$ is infinite, then, since isolated points are open, writing $S$ as the disjoint union of two infinite sets gives what's needed.

Suppose $S$ is finite. Then since $M$ is infinite, there are distinct elements  $m_1$ and $m_2$ of $M\setminus S$. Choose disjoint open nhoods  $N_1$ of $m_1$ and $N_2$ of $m_2$. Both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are infinite since $m_1$ and $m_2$ are not isolated. Taking $U=N_1$, then, gives what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

as fast answer I would suggest to construct by induction such set.

Being that an open set is a set where every point contains an open neightbourhood completely contained insided the original set. I will try first to demonstrate that such set with an added point is a new set still open. Then by induction. 
The key point is the induction step